# where can I get plugin.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I need `plugin.jar` so that I can use

```
import netscape.javascript.*;
```

I already have `JRE 7.6` running on my mac in eclipse. But the plugin is not there. Is there a way to import it directly from eclipse? Else, where would I find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for the plugin.jar normally located in your jre\lib folder. You will need to include that one explicitly in your eclipse project I guess

btw. don't forget to set the MAYSCRIPT attribute on your applet tag in order to explicitly enable java-js communication which normally is disabled by default for security reasons

Comment: it's not there. How would I add it?

Answer (score 0):

Click 'Add External JARs'...

[image]

It's here...

`/System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Resources/Java/plugin.jar`